Show Quarto table chunks in the outline
Is there a way to show the caption or the label of Quarto table R chunks like
```{r}
#| label: tbl-recap
#| tbl-cap: "**My table.**"
#| tbl-pos: H
#| output: asis
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
df
```

In the outline in RStudio?
